# is there a website or a python function that create a DataFrame examples code?

Tags: python, dataframe, function

is there a website or a function that create a DataFrame examples code so that it can be used in tutorials?

something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':    [ 3,  29],
               'height': [94, 170],
               'weight': [31, 115]})
```

or

```
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
```

or

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],'Age':[28,34,29,42]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easy to create a few example dataframes of your own or to use data from the hundreds of open data sources ?

Comment: maybe , but I want to crate an example code that had the sample data in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get over **750 datasets** from [pydataset](https://github.com/iamaziz/PyDataset) 
`pip install pydataset`

**To see a list of the datasets:**

```
from pydataset import data

# To see a list of the datasets
print(data())
```

#### Output:

```
        dataset_id                                             title
0    AirPassengers       Monthly Airline Passenger Numbers 1949-1960
1          BJsales                 Sales Data with Leading Indicator
2              BOD                         Biochemical Oxygen Demand
3     Formaldehyde                     Determination of Formaldehyde
4     HairEyeColor         Hair and Eye Color of Statistics Students
..             ...                                               ...
752        VerbAgg                  Verbal Aggression item responses
753           cake                 Breakage Angle of Chocolate Cakes
754           cbpp                 Contagious bovine pleuropneumonia
755    grouseticks  Data on red grouse ticks from Elston et al. 2001
756     sleepstudy       Reaction times in a sleep deprivation study

[757 rows x 2 columns]
```

#### Usage

And to use one of the **example datasets in a dataframe**, it is as simple as using the `dataset_id`:

```
from pydataset import data

df = data('cake')
print(df)
```

#### Output:

```
     replicate recipe  temperature  angle  temp
1            1      A          175     42   175
2            1      A          185     46   185
3            1      A          195     47   195
4            1      A          205     39   205
5            1      A          215     53   215
..         ...    ...          ...    ...   ...
266         15      C          185     28   185
267         15      C          195     25   195
268         15      C          205     25   205
269         15      C          215     31   215
270         15      C          225     25   225

[270 rows x 5 columns]
```

#### Note:

There are other packages with their own functionality. Or you can create your own.
You can get over **17000 datasets** from the [datasets](https://pypi.org/project/datasets/) package:
`pip install datasets`

To **list** all of the datasets:

```
from datasets import list_datasets

# Print all the available datasets
print(list_datasets())
```